# php and sql IN operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called business_directory which holds information about local businesses. I can produce listings from the table without any issues, however I now want to create a list which only contains businesses which meet a certain criteria, ie their business_type is either Cafe, Restaurant, Public House or Take Away. I am creating 3 arrays, one for each listing type, ie Featured Listing, Standard Listing or Complimentary Listing and this element works fine when listing all records, however when I try to amend my code to only include the above business types I get no records found.

My original code which worked fine was (I will only show one array to save confusion)

```
list($business_directoryRecordscomp, $business_directoryMetaData) = getRecords(array(
'tableName' => 'business_directory',
'orderBy' => 'RAND()', 'where' => 'comp_listing = 1', 
));
```

To filter the results I have amended this to

```
list($business_directoryRecordscomp, $business_directoryMetaData) = getRecords(array(
'tableName'   => 'business_directory',
'orderBy'     => 'RAND()', 'where'              => 'comp_listing = 1 and business_type IN ("Cafe","Restaurant","Public House","Take Away Food")'  ));
```

but it results in no records being found.

the "business_type" field is a multvalue list field so can contain more than one business type, ie Restaurant and Take Away however many listings do contain just one business type and it isn't finding those records either.

I have looked around the web and the above syntax seems to be correct so I am at a loss to understand why it fails to find any records that match. I have double checked spellings etc and cannot find anything wrong.

Unfortunately I am not a php programmer nor do I have sql knowledge so it would be appreciated if responses were kept as simple as possible or explained in detail so that I am able to understand.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

For those asking about getRecords it may be to do with a php file that is called before the list element. the file has 1500 lines of code but perhaps the following excerpt may help

I found this near tyhe top of the page if it helps. Sorry but I have tried a number of times to get it to insert into a code box but for some reason it leaves the first half out.

```
list($records, $details) = getRecords(array(
  'tableName'           => 'listings', // REQUIRED, error if not specified, tableName is prefixed with $TABLE_PREFIX
  'where'               => '',         // optional, defaults to blank
  'orderBy'             => '',         // optional, defaults to $_REQUEST['orderBy'], or table sort order
  'limit'               => '',         // optional, defaults to blank
  'offset'              => '',         // optional, defaults to blank (if set but no limit then limit is set to high number as per mysql docs)
  'perPage'             => '',         // optional, number of records to show per page
  'pageNum'             => '',         // optional, page number to display defaults to $_REQUEST['page'] or 1
  'allowSearch'         => '',         // optional, defaults to yes, adds search info from query string
  'requireSearchMatch'  => '',         // optional, don't show any results unless search keyword submitted and matched
  'requireSearchSuffix' => '',         // optional, search fields must end in a suffix such as _match or _keyword, original field=value match search is ignored
  'loadUploads'         => '',         // optional, defaults to yes, loads upload array into upload field
  'loadCreatedBy'       => '',         // optional, defaults to yes, adds createdBy. fields for created user
  'loadListDetails'     => '',         // optional, defaults to yes, adds $details with prev/next page, etc info
  'loadPseudoFields'    => false,      // optional, defaults to yes, adds additional fields for :text, :label, :values, etc
  'orWhere'             => '',         // optional, adding " OR ... " to end of where clause
  'useSeoUrls'          => false,      // optional, use SEO urls, defaults to no

  'leftJoin'      => array(        // Note: leftJoins require you to use fully qualified fieldnames in WHERE and ORDER BY, such as tablename.fieldname
    'grocery_aisle' => 'aisleNum', // foreign table => local field (that matches num in foreign table)
    'brands'        => 'brandNum',
    'otherTable'    => 'ON mainTable.foreignKey = foreignTable.num',
  ),

  'ignoreHidden'            => false,  // don't hide records with hidden flag set
  'ignorePublishDate'       => false,  // don't hide records with publishDate > now
  'ignoreRemoveDate'        => false,  // don't hide records with removeDate < now
  'includeDisabledAccounts' => true,   // include records that were created by disabled accounts.  See: Admin > Section Editors > Advanced > Disabled Accounts

  'addSelectExpr'           => 'NOW() as _currentDate',   // add expression to SELECT, useful for generating pseudo-fields or calculated values
  'groupBy'                 => '',                        // optional, defaults to blank
  'having'                  => '',                        // optional, defaults to blank

  'useCache'      => true,       // use cache - requires cache plugin
  'debugSql'      => false,      // optional, display SQL query, defaults to no
));
```

Comment: what is there in getRecords(). i think the query is having some syntax error.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question, if it helps the code all works until I add and business_type IN ("Cafe","Restaurant","Public House","Take Away Food")

Comment: you are using getRecords() function for fetching data.what code does that function contains?

Comment: I am sorry I dont know, that code is produced automatically by a content management software builder called cmsb, as mentioned I am not a php or sql programmer, most of the code I use is pre created by the cmsb software. As mentioned it does all work if I want to display all the listings, it is only when I add the additional element and business_type IN ("Cafe","Restaurant","Public House","Take Away Food") that it stops working.

Comment: try to pass 'where' before 'orderBy'.it may work.http://www.interactivetools.com/docs/cmsbuilder/viewer_options.html

Comment: Hi tried changing order to  list($business_directoryRecordscomp, $business_directoryMetaData) = getRecords(array(
    'tableName'   => 'business_directory',
     'where' => 'comp_listing = 1 and business_type IN ("Cafe","Restaurant","Public House","Take Away Food")', 'orderBy'     => 'RAND()'
  )); but exactly the same result, no records found.

Comment: look what that function is building and you may get the actual problem.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help your without knowing the SQL that is generated by that getRecords() function. Try to find a php file that contains `function getRecords` and show it here.